# How to use google API Key into a CDN link get json format for fetch user's current Address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I want to set User's current location for my website, I use `java script` geographical location, I got user's longitude and latitude, then I tried to change that into a address format, so I'm using google maps content delivery network link with my google maps applet programming interface  key, and then I pass my Content delivery network link with that longitude and latitude on my browser, but it show some JavaScript Object Notation format error message like following code,

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

What should I do for solve this issue ?

I have tried on a e-learn website html geographical location and then I added some java script codes.

I need to show a user current location like an address on my navigation bar, when user click the location icon.

Comment: Go here: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard, click Library on the left, then search for / click on the "Maps JavaScript API" and enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a CDN (Content Delivery Network), which serves files, but an API (Application Programming Interface).

You need to log in to your [Google developers console](https://console.cloud.google.com).

Then in the navigation menu on the left, go to `APIs & services > Credentials`.

Here you have your API keys, you can enable/disable restrictions to applications, domains and IP addresses that can use this key.

Unless you explicitely authorise your application to use this key, access will be denied.

Comment: I got the API key and enabled the restrictions,but when pass the API key in the code i am  getting error: ({
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}) .In my code i passed the API key here("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIzaSyAFI520w8u6ftcf0_Goa_4dUV3pixOSJ2A&latlng="+position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude+"&sensor=true") whether it is correct? if wrong where should i pass the API key?